# find an undetermined numeric value in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, set

I have a text-file that looks like this...

```
91 bytes (91 B) copied, 0.0127056 s, 7.2 kB/s
91 bytes (91 B) copied, 0.00295891 s, 30.8 kB/s
91 bytes (91 B) copied, 0.0146195 s, 6.2 kB/s
91 bytes (91 B) copied, 0.029734 s, 3.1 kB/
91 bytes (91 B) copied, 0.0641979 s, 1.4 kB/s
```

What I want to do is run a test to make sure all the values 'xx bytes' are the same. 
I need to know how to specify the number 'xx' as it is an undetermined number.  I can already do it with the "set" command but I want to make sure the value is a number that precedes the string "bytes"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to...1) make sure it is a number. 2.) ensure it's placement relative to the word "bytes"  3.) test to see if they are all the same.

Comment: are the xx bytes always at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If awk solution is ok then, you can do:

```
awk '{if( $1==$1+0 && $2 == "bytes" ) a[$1]++;} \
     END{ if(a[$1] != NR) print "fail"; \
          else print "pass"}' file
```

`$1==$1+0` - to make sure first column is a number.
`$2 == "bytes"` - 2nd column is "bytes".
`a[$1] != NR` - to ensure number of records match the number of lines that where processed.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{a[$1]}END{print length(a)==1?"YES":"NO"}' file
```

with your input example, it will print `"YES"` , if you change some number e.g `91 bytes -> 92 bytes`, it will print `"NO"`

Comment: +1; clever. Caveat: applying `length()` to _arrays_ is not POSIX-compliant, and the default `awk` on some Linux platforms is `mawk`, where this will NOT work - you'd have to count the keys in a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is probably the way to go, but here is another solution:

```
if (( $(grep -Po "^\d+(?= bytes)" file | uniq | wc -l) <= 1 )); then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

`<=` is used to print `yes` in case of the empty file. Feel free to use `==` instead if you count that as `no`.

Answer (score 0):

sort -u, prevents duplicate values in the list.

So, if all the values are equals, it should return a single row.

```
if [ `cat my_file | awk '{if ($2 == "bytes") print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "Yes"
else
   echo "No"
fi
```

Comment: This answer does not make any sense. First of all, you don't have to use ``cat``, just pass the filename to awk like this ``awk '{print $1}' file``, secondly you don't need ``sort``, because it will waste time sorting the values. What you need is ``uniq``. Thirdly it does not satisfy the requirement to find 'xx bytes' strings. See my answer instead.